# How to order in django on two columns when one of the column is null

Tags: python, django

I would like to order the dataset based upon the two columns let's say created_date and updated_date.

If updated_date is null it should order be using created_date otherwise using updated_date column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work with a [**`.annotate()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) and then [**`.order_by(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#order-by):

```
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce

MyModel.objects.annotate(
    my_date=Coalesce('updated_date', 'created_date')
).order_by('my_date')
```

Since [django-3.2](/questions/tagged/django-3.2) you can work with [**`.alias(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#alias) to prevent calculating this both as column and in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce

MyModel.objects.alias(
    my_date=Coalesce('updated_date', 'created_date')
).order_by('my_date')
```